# How to show/hide column(s) on complex header in a Data Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, datatables

I have run into trouble while working with Data Tables with jQuery. I have a table with dynamic column header generation (which also determines the colspan value) and the actual complex header text.

I am then populating my data table with the data that I receive from an API.

Problem: Once the data table is loaded, I have used the Button's option show/hide columns but the problem is that I always receive the columns that are not in colspan or have exactly one column.

I wanted a solution where I could show/hide my column(s) based on my complex generated header.

Sample structure:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Main Header</th>
   <th colspan="2">Main Header 1</th>
   <th colspan="5">Main Header 2</th>
   <th colspan="3">Main Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Sub Header</td>
   <td>Sub Header 1</td>
   <td>Sub Header 2</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<!-- DATA FOR TABLE GOES HERE -->
</table>
```

So basically my question is that I want to show/hide column based on my Main Header but when I initialize the show/hide feature of data table using Buttons, it always catches the sub headers and only those main headers whose colspan is 0.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k0afsmzt/

I am trying to show/hide columns based on Main Header(s) but the data tables plugin only shows the sub headers when you click the column visibility button.

Comment: Datatable is a plugin that dynamically renders new elements. When you use the pagination, filtering, etc. functions, new element are draw each time. I suggest you to do a close reading of [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/)  and **try something**. There is no code of your attempt here, and the issues/requirements are unclear. -- Voting to close as too braod.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I am sorry if I was being unclear in my question. Basically I wanted to ask that if there is a way to show/hide columns based on complex headers that span across multiple sub columns. I cannot show my attempt since the data is sensitive, hence I created a demo table example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Then please, post a working demo as much as close to your real table. You can do it on SO, using what they call a ["snippet"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) --**preferably**-- or external websites like [CodePen](https://codepen.io/) or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) --- Please include your attempts. SO is not a coding service. We can **help** but not code on request. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Roger that! I got a fiddle example working for you. If you will see the column visibility button returns only the sub headers to show/hide columns. I am trying to hide the column on the Main Header(s). Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k0afsmzt/

Comment: I updated [your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/1vbrfuqk/) by just numbering the "sample data" like the sub headers (0 to 6) and played with the column visibility buttons. I see no issue.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I see what you did and the column visibility button shows the sub headers (0-6) when you click it. But I am looking for a way to show/hide the columns based on Main Header(1-2). Basically the column visibility button should show the Main Header list and when I click on a Main Header, it should hide the entire spanned column. Right now, only the columns under a sub header are hidden when you select them from the column visibility button.

Comment: Ho I understand now... But it does not seem to be possible from what DataTables has to offer out of the box. You will need to code it yourself... Probably using [column().visible()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible())

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I did try that but since the data including the headers and sub headers is being generated dynamically, I am running into all sort of problems. And there are also not enough examples for reference. :(

Answer (score 1):

You try to show/hide the columns **but not the headers**.
*(I assume that because how would the user unhide the columns, if not?)*

> ... there are also not enough examples for reference...

I agree. So I made something I hope you will like.

Since I found that playing with DataTable's [column().visible()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().visible()) simply is not rendering the "hidden" columns **including the headers**, and that is causing more new issues that it solves... I found an alternative way to achieve something close to your needs.

In the demo below, I played with the CSS [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property. An additionnal advantage is that the table keeps it's original width all the time.

Now on table draw triggered by pagination or search... The columns hiding may not be kept all the time... **I'm leaving you that fun to test it out** with some real data over more than one dataTable's page.

I think that is a good starter. I coded way more than I should have... Play with it and customize it to your taste. If there is some more issue arising, post another question **including what you tried** to fix.

Also on [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bzVwOp?editors=1111).

Please run the snippet below in *full page* mode.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myTable = $('#mytable').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'colvis'
    ],
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
      $("#mytable thead th").show();
    } 
  });

  $('#mytable').on("click","th",function(){

    console.clear();
    
    // Get the TH column "from"
    var colFrom = parseInt($(this).data("col_from"));
    //console.log(colFrom);

    // Get the TH column "to"
    var colTo = parseInt($(this).data("col_to"));
    //console.log(colTo);

    // Toggle the columns under the TH
    for(i=colFrom;i<colTo+1;i++){
      
      //myTable.column( i ).visible( !myTable.column( i ).visible() );
      $("#mytable tbody tr").each(function(){
        var TD = $(this).find("td").eq(i);
        
        // Toggle visibility
        var toggleCol = (TD.css("visibility")=="visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
        console.log("TOGGLING COL# "+i+" to "+toggleCol);
        TD.css({"visibility":toggleCol})
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table{
  border:0px !important;
}
th,td{
  border:1px solid black !important;
}
thead th{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/site-examples.css?_=19472395a2969da78c8a4c707e72123a"-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>

<!-- Main Table Structure -->
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-col_from="0" data-col_to="0">Main Header</th>
      <th colspan="2" data-col_from="1" data-col_to="2">Main Header 1</th>
      <th colspan="4" data-col_from="3" data-col_to="6">Main Header 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sub Header 0</td>
      <td>Sub Header 1</td>
      <td>Sub Header 2</td>
      <td>Sub Header 3</td>
      <td>Sub Header 4</td>
      <td>Sub Header 5</td>
      <td>Sub Header 6</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample Data 0</td>
      <td>Sample Data 1</td>
      <td>Sample Data 2</td>
      <td>Sample Data 3</td>
      <td>Sample Data 4</td>
      <td>Sample Data 5</td>
      <td>Sample Data 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- DATA FOR TABLE GOES HERE -->
</table>
```